# Redis large key space schema

Tags: redis, schema, database, nosql

My application works by using SINTER, SDIFF and SUNION on different keys, (which contain one or more ids), to get a result. Now I need to add a new key to my database which is in the form of idx:cookie:[random_alphanumeric_string]. But this may have many random keys and it will be hard to maintain because of large number of keys (100K keys, maybe more).

Is there a better way to store the keys, keeping in mind maintainability and how my app works.

Comment: Have you seen the Data Types [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/data-types)? You can probably use a [hash](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes)

Comment: I did and tried using hash to store these keys but again this is hard for maintaining. If I like to update the hash I need to go over all hash keys and update each of them.